# About the way to take Windows Services

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, appdomain

I'm an intermediate C# programmer and I'm getting ready for Exam 70-536, my question is where I can find a good example about windows services built in .net platform.

If you already done windows services ... can you tell me about  your service?

What would be a clear example that I should do to get this topic right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good tutorial to start with windows services :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx